# $ x $ and $ y $ coordinates in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

I'm trying to make a `ListLinePlot` with my randomly generated data, and I want one vector to be the `x` coordinates of the graph, and another vector to be the `y` coordinates of the graph.

If I add those to the plot, it just gives me 2 graphs, both of which use the numbers in the vectors as the `y` coordinates, and the positions in the vectors (1, 2, 3, etc.) as the `x` coordinates. 
I can't type out all the coordinates, because the vectors are generated at random, and their sizes are generated at random (I'm taking them from a randomly generated matrix.)

Is this possible? How do I do this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: if you have the xVector and the yVector, the data you want to plot are of the form data=Transpose[{xVector,yVector}]

Comment: Thank you very much!